# Should [meaning] and [meaning-in-context] be mutually exclusive?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

[meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) and [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) have a fairly high [overlap rate of 26%](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/185919/tag-associated-with-other-tags?Limit=250&LeftTag=meaning&RightTag=meaning-in-context&TagCountFilter=10&PerFilter=0) which means that 26% of all questions tagged [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) are *also* tagged [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning). The [full list of ~375](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning+meaning-in-context) don't reveal anything terribly interesting about the association. It seems that our taggers consider [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) a subtag of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning).

But here are the relevant tag-wikis:

> #### [About](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/meaning/info) [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning)
>
> This tag should be used for questions asking about nuances of meaning and definitions for a word or phrase. For a good explanation of how to write a good [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) question, please read this blog article.
>
> If you are asking about the meaning of a word in a given context, please use the more specific [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) instead.
>
> For questions relating to the origin of a word, its evolution over time, or the earliest known citation, [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) should be used.

---

> #### [About](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/meaning-in-context/info) [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context)
>
> [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) is for questions about understanding English speech, or writing at a level above individual words or phrases.
>
> Oftentimes, the literal meaning of a word or idiom is clear, but it's not obvious what the significance is of that word in the context of a whole paragraph or article. This tag also marks requests for help understanding allusions to literature, pop culture, politics, current events, or other elements of English language usage which depend on a broader context.

The tag-wiki for [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) explicitly notes that you should use [meaning-in-context](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) *instead* of [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) when relevant so it seems that these are intended to be mutually exclusive tags.

Is this intention still accurate? Do we still want to explicitly distinguish between these two tags?

Comment: Maybe [meaning] should be changed to [meaning-no-context].